# TeamCity fails to load build settings from VCS, ignores new settings

Tags: git, teamcity, teamcity-9.1

We have a TeamCity project configured with with [Versioned Settings](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Storing+Project+Settings+in+Version+Control).
It has a build which fails with the message `Failed to load build settings from VCS`.

We think we have understood the cause of this (There is two build configuration xml files that have the same name). So we have modified the appropriate files under the `.teamcity` folder, committed the changes and pushed to git.

However, TeamCity is not detecting or applying our modifications. In fact, we see clearly in the build log that TeamCity is still reading the build settings from the commit previous to the commit with the fix.

So, for some reason TeamCity keeps reading the old configuration. We have now done several commits to after the fix, but it makes no difference.

[The documentation](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Storing+Project+Settings+in+Version+Control) states that you can push the button `Commit current project settings...` to synchronize the settings. But we have tried doing so, and that did not help either.

We are using TeamCity Enterprise 9.1.3 (build 37176)

Comment: @Shravan40 that doesn't really apply here. I have no direct access to the TeamCity server. The commits are generated by TeamCity, so you can't really interact with the git staging area.

Answer (score 1):

What seems to have worked for me, was going to the affected project's overview page, clicking the "Actions" dropdown button, an choosing "Enforce clean checkout". That, combined with a TeamCity server restart, and it picked up the branch-specific VCS settings again.

[image: Enforcing a clean checkout]